# How to have multiple ways of specifying the Control variable in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

Consider the following as an example:

```
DynamicModule[{
    $Return
},
    Manipulate[
        $Return=$Dollars+$Quarters/4;(*first line*)
        Row[{"Value of $Return that will be used: ",DecimalForm[N@$Return,{16,2}]}],
        
        {{$Return,10,"Return"},3/4,20,1/4},
        {{$Dollars,10,"Dollars"},0,20,1,ControlType->Setter},
        {{$Quarters,0,"Quarters"},0,3,1,ControlType->Setter},
        
        ControlPlacement->Top
    ]
]
```

This produces an interface where I can specify the value of `$Return` that can be changed via the `Setters` and the `Slider` adjusts accordingly.

If I change the (*first line*) in `Manipulate` to

```
{$Dollars,$Quarters}={1,4}*MixedFractionParts@$Return;
```

Then the `Slider` gives the `$Return` value and the `Setters` adjust accordingly.

Is there a way to make this `Manipulate` have both the `Slider` and the `Setters` be a way to specify the `$Return` value and the others adjusting accordingly?

One more thing, lets say I want to restrict `$Return` to be in the range from `3/4` to `20` which means if the `$Dollars Setter` is set to `0` then the `$Quarters Setter` should grey out the options `0`, `1` and `2` and similarly for `20` the options `1`, `2` and `3`.

This is just a toy example with example numbers so if the mechanism is general then that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use the option [`TrackingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackingFunction.html) in each control to dynamically change the other two control values.

Define three tracking functions for the three control variables:

```
trackingFunc$R = ($Return = Round[#, 1/4];
    {$Dollars, $Quarters} = {1, 4} MixedFractionParts@#;) &;

trackingFunc$D = ($Dollars = #;
    $Return = Min[20, Max[# + $Quarters/4, 3/4]];
    $Quarters = If[# == 20, 0, If[# == 0, 3, $Quarters]];) &;

trackingFunc$Q = ($Quarters = #;
    $Return = Min[20, Max[$Dollars + #/4, 3/4]];) &;
```

Use these as the option values for `TrackingFunction` in controls:

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{"Value of $Return that will be used: ", 
      DecimalForm[N @ $Return, {16, 2}]}],
 {{$Return, 10, "Return"},
   Manipulator[#, {3/4., 20., 1./4}] &,
   Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"},
   TrackingFunction -> trackingFunc$R,  
   DefaultOptions ->
     {Slider -> {ImageMargins -> 5},
       InputField -> {Alignment -> {Left, Center}, ImageSize -> {50, 30}}}},
 {{$Dollars, 10, "Dollars"}, 0, 20, 1,
    Setter,
    TrackingFunction -> trackingFunc$D},
 {{$Quarters, 0, "Quarters"}, 
    If[$Return == 3/4 || $Dollars == 0, {3}, 
       If[$Return == 20 || $Dollars == 20, {0}, Range[0, 3]]],
    SetterBar,
    TrackingFunction -> trackingFunc$Q},
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]

Comment: How are you recording this and the mouse movement?

Comment: @morbo, I am using the app [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Temp = 10.0;

Manipulate[
 If[$Temp == $Return,
  $Return = $Dollars + $Quarters/4,
  ($Dollars = IntegerPart[$Return];
   $Quarters = 4 ($Return - $Dollars))];
 $Temp = $Return;
 Row[{"Value of Return that will be used: ", 
   DecimalForm[$Return // N, {4, 2}]}],
 {{$Return, 10, "Return"}, 0, 20, 1/4},
 {{$Dollars, 10, "Dollars"}, 0, 20, 1, ControlType -> Setter},
 {{$Quarters, 0, "Quarters"}, 0, 3, 1, ControlType -> Setter},
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]